# How to write CASE WHEN in WHERE Clause in Postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql

How to have a CASE WHEN in WHERE clause in PostgresSQL?

I don't want to scan all partitions of a table. And depending on a variable, I want to scan only a specific partition.

```
SELECT 
t.CUSTOMER_ID
, CASE 
    WHEN t.col1 = 'U' THEN 1
    WHEN t.col1 = 'E' THEN 2
    WHEN t.col1 = 'J' THEN 3
ELSE 0 END AS col1_id
, max(t.date) AS date

FROM t

WHERE 
date > CAST('${date}' AS TIMESTAMP)
    AND st = 'Y'
    and RSS = 'wallet'
    and cob NOT IN (1,2,3,4,5)
    AND CASE 
            WHEN ${mp_id} IN (1,2,3) THEN col1 = 'U'  --this CASE WHEN is not working
            WHEN ${mp_id} IN (4,5,6) THEN col1 = 'E' 
            WHEN ${mp_id} IN (7,8,9) THEN col1 = 'J' 
    END
```

That CASE WHEN in the WHERE is wrong. I am doing it to only scan the partition 'U' in case the variable ${mp_id} is in (1,2,3) or only scan partition 'E' of the table, if the variable ${mp_id} is in (4,5,6) etc.

How would be the right syntax for that CASE WHEN in the WHERE clause?

Thank you!

Comment: It's generally better to use regular AND/OR instead of case expressions in the WHERE clause.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do it like this:

```
col1 = CASE 
        WHEN ${mp_id} IN (1,2,3) THEN 'U' 
        WHEN ${mp_id} IN (4,5,6) THEN 'E' 
        WHEN ${mp_id} IN (7,8,9) THEN 'J' 
      END
```

Remember, the `CASE` keyword is for **expressions**. It produces a value; it does not select which code to run like an `if` statement.

---

I know this edit is old now, but it just came into my feed again so people still see it, and today I'd instead look to do this with a `JOIN` to [a `VALUES()` expression](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-values.html) (they're not just for `INSERT` statements!)

```
FROM t
INNER JOIN (VALUES 
    ('U', 1), ('U', 2), ('U', 3), 
    ('E', 4), ('E', 5), ('E', 6),
    ('J', 7), ('J', 8), ('J', 9)
) as map(mpID, rslt) ON map.mpID = ${mp_id} AND map.rslt = col1
WHERE date > CAST('${date}' AS TIMESTAMP)
    AND st = 'Y'
    AND RSS = 'wallet'
    AND cob NOT IN (1,2,3,4,5)
```

Answer (score 2):

It's generally better to use regular `AND`/`OR` instead of `case` *expressions* in the `WHERE` clause.

```
WHERE 
date > CAST('${date}' AS TIMESTAMP)
    AND st = 'Y'
    and RSS = 'wallet'
    and cob NOT IN (1,2,3,4,5)
    AND ((${mp_id} IN (1,2,3) AND col1 = 'U') OR
         (${mp_id} IN (4,5,6) AND col1 = 'E') OR 
         (${mp_id} IN (7,8,9) AND col1 = 'J'))
```